# Mendix iFrame - Page not found

Tags: iframe, mendix

I have created multiple custom .html pages and placed them in /themes in my project. To use these custom pages in my project, I am using iFrame widget, which is placed in a dataview and all the settings are done correctly as I have used this widget previously as well. When I navigate to this page with widget using iFrame, it works fine the first time and displays the page correctly. However, after first time, no link to any of the pages works and gives an error "Page Not Found". Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here or guide me to a different/better solution to achieve this? 
Note: I have also tried the same with iFrame tag inside HTML Snippet, and the behaviour is exactly same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake is that people use just the filename instead of complete url in iframe url property. Try changing the filename to complete url e.g. http://example.com/file.html instead of file.html.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.